# How to delete web service in AzureML with mystery endpoint

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have an AzureML free account in South Central US. At some point I set up a web service, which I no longer need. I also suspect it's blocking my other web services as I'm getting 503 errors whenever I try to use them.

When I try to delete the web service it gives the error message:
`Cannot delete web service "azuremlweb" because one or more additional endpoints were created for it. These endpoints must be deleted before you can delete the web service.`

I didn't intentionally set up any extra endpoints and when trying to follow the instructions [on this doc page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/machine-learning-manage-workspace/) I couldn't see any endpoints listed that I can remove.

[image]

The only unusual thing I can think of about the service was that it had multiple inputs.

I've more or less deleted everything in the workspace now: experiments, other web services, but it still won't go. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use Azure ML PowerShell module to discover and delete web service endpoints, and web service.

http://aka.ms/amlps

Comment: Interestingly the Powershell module says there are 0 endpoints.

Comment: Great! Deleting the web service from here worked. When I went back to AzureML Studio it was gone. Thanks!